# This is meant to be a function that decrypts an encrypted text from the dictionary and the should output CAB BA, instead it gives a longer result

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

The encryption works quite well to give "JOP PO". But the decryption of this same "JOP PO" in the decryption part gives "CABBA" instead of "CAB BA".
and when I include an elif under the decryption loop it gives me some long stuff like "jjjjjcjjooooaooppppbpp   pppppbppoooaoo"

```
en_dict = {'A' : 'O', 'B' : 'P', 'C' : 'J', 'Z' : 'Z', '0' : 9, '1' : 8, '8' : 1, '9' : 0}

unencrypted_item = "cAb ba"
unencrypted_item = unencrypted_item.upper()

def encrypt(unencrypted_data):
    result = ""
    for i in unencrypted_item:
        if i not in en_dict:
            result+=i
        else:    
            result+=en_dict[i]
    return result

print(encrypt(unencrypted_item))

encrypted_item = "jop po"
encrypted_item = encrypted_item.upper()

def decrypt(enc_data):
    result = ""
    for i in encrypted_item:
        for n,o in en_dict.items():
            if i == o:
                result += n
    return result


print(decrypt(encrypted_item))`
```

Comment: You're passing in your string as `enc_data`, but working on some variable called `encrypted_item`. Something's not right there

Comment: enc_data is just part of the function name. It can take whatever argument (file_name, data, encrypted_item, etc) and doesn't affect the general work of the function

Comment: You've not understood what the function arguments are for. If your code works at all it's down to a property of scope.

Comment: In any case, we don't know from the code you've posted whether the original data was properly encrypted, and we also don't know whether the contents of your dictionary are what you think they are. See [mcve]

Comment: Run on your vs code if you think the code doesn't work, The dictionary contents were given specifically and I'm not meant to edit it. I didn't add the code I used for the encryption cause it works fine (minimal code for issue as stated in the link you dropped) while the word to be decrypted was picked by me and from the value of each key in the dictionary  but I'll edit the post and add the encryption code and the code without my else which gives the result as CABBA but without a space.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by unzipping the dictionary to get the keys and values. Then I reassigned the values as the keys and the keys as the values.

````
encrypted_item = "jop po"
encrypted_item = encrypted_item.upper()

def decrypt(enc_data):
    [*alpha],[*enc_key] = zip(*en_dict.items())
    dec_dict = dict(zip(enc_key,alpha))
    result = ""
    for i in encrypted_item:
        if i not in dec_dict:
            result += i 
        else:
            result += dec_dict[i] 
    return result

        


print(decrypt(encrypted_item))    ```
````